# How to get the 10000 locations from database in java based on performance wise?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

How to get the 10000 locations from database in java based on performance wise

In my date base location table have  10000 locations is there, 
iam getting the locations based on hibernate query("from Locaion") in sping controller
but my view page loading time is very slow 
how it solved
pls tell me

my code is:

```
List<Location> locations= mservive.getlocatins();
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Location");            
List<Location> loc=query.list();            
return loc;
```

I'm using auto complete option using in loading for locations in view layer

Comment: Add the code you're using.

Comment: Thak you Harry for your response

Comment: You have 10000 locations. It will be slow. Do u need to send all the 10,000 records in the WS? Consider paginating the response.

Comment: iam using auto complete option using in loading for locations in view layer

Answer (score 1):

Fetching 1000+ locations in a single query is never going to be efficient like that. You need to look at paging the data, or change your database design.

I am not sure exactly how your DB is made, but if you really need this kind of data, better option is to place it in a single column ( like XML) , fetch it in a single row and then process that in Java.
Which DB you are using? 
Is your data static or going to change?
How often do you need to change this data?
The design can be changed once we consider the above mentioned questions.

If its not possible to change the design, look at paging, fetch only the number of records needed to display on the page, and let the remaining come later when user clicks next.
Hope this helps.

Comment: iam using mysql db

Comment: iam using auto complete option using in loading for locations in view layer

Comment: Then you can try few things a.) you could try and restrict the locations by called auto complete only after user has entered one or two characters so that the results are less b:) you could still fetch only top 10 records , it does not make sense to show 10000 entries for auto fill c) you could look at saving the data in a static file, since its unlike to change in a major way.  Will request rest of the community to contribute more options.